# Does addAll() return false?

Tags: java, collections

While looking at the source code of CollectionUtils addAll method. I notice it uses `|=` symbol

```
public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements) {
 boolean result = false;
 for (T element : elements)
    result |= c.add(element);

 return result;
}
```

From my understanding `|=` is a [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator and just a shorthand of `result = result|c.add(element)`, so for example :

```
System.out.println(false|true); //true
System.out.println(false|false); //false
System.out.println(true|false); //true
System.out.println(true|true); //true
```

This means that if any item successfully added, it will return true. 
Now I've been wondering is there will be an instance, it will return false? If not why it has a return?

Comment: Try `set.addAll(set)` for arbitrary `Set<Whatever>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah. I did the same and the result pumped up :)

Comment: thanks. I forgot the Set. So if I use List it will always return true, since it can contain duplicate values.

Comment: Well, except for an empty list.

Comment: How does that even add more than one element since it returns after first iteration in the loop?

Comment: @ViktorMellgren I fixed the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all the elements to be added were already in the Collection (prior to the call to addAll), and the Collection doesn't allow duplicates, it will return false, since all the individual `add` method calls would return false. This is true for Collections such as `Set`.

For other Collections, `add` always returns true, and therefore `addAll` would return true, unless you call it with an empty list of elements to be added.

Comment: Thanks. So a List will always return true? because it allows duplicates.

Comment: @user23123412 Yes (assuming you pass a non empty array of elements to add), since `add` for List always returns true.

Answer (score 3):

`|=` is [bitwise OR](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html)

| (Bitwise OR) sets a bit to 1 if one or both of the corresponding bits in its operands are 1, and to 0 if both of the corresponding bits are 0. In other words, | returns one in all cases except where the corresponding bits of both operands are zero. The resulting bit pattern is the "set" (1 or true) bits of any of the two operands. This property is used to "set" or "turn on" a "flag" (bit set to one) in your flags or options variable regardless of whether that flag was set previously or not. Multiple flag bits can be set if a combo MASK is defined.

```
// To set or turn on a flag bit(s)
flags = flags | MASK;
// or, more succintly
flags |= MASK;
```

So your code is equivalent to:

```
boolean result = false;
for (T element : elements){
   result = result | c.add(element);
}
return result;
```

Initially result will be **false** and as one of elements successfully get added to collection will be set to true i.e `c.add(element);`. **So it will return true if one of elements get added.**

Answer (score 2):

From docs of [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...))

> returns:
>
> true if the collection changed as a result of the call.

If the collections not at all modified, then false.

Consider the below program.(follow the result in comments)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l1= new ArrayList<String>();
        l1.add("test");
        List<String> l2= new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(l2.addAll(l1));//true
        System.out.println(l2.addAll(l1));//true
        
        Set<String> s1= new HashSet<String>();
        s1.add("test");
        Set<String> s2= new HashSet<String>();
        System.out.println(s2.addAll(s1));//true
        System.out.println(s2.addAll(s1));//false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Operation : all of the elements in the specified collection appends to the end of this list. 
if the collection changed as a result of the call then it returns true.
if the collection not changed as a result of the call then it returns false.